# Laravel 5.1 Relationship - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, constraints, relationship

I have 3 tables users, posts and comments. The relationship between users and posts is ok. I can store new posts. But if I comment a post, I get this error message:

**Error message**

> QueryException in Connection.php line 631:
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_post_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `comments` (`body`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (new comment, 1, 2015-07-20 14:16:07, 2015-07-20 14:16:07))

**Migration users**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Migration posts**

```
Schema::create( 'posts', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
        $table->increments( 'id' );
        $table->integer( 'user_id' )->unsigned();
        $table->string( 'title' );
        $table->text( 'body' );
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign( 'user_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'users' );
    } );
```

**Migration comments**

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments( 'id' );
        $table->integer( 'user_id' )->unsigned();
        $table->integer( 'post_id' )->unsigned();
        $table->text( 'body' );
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign( 'user_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'users' );
        $table->foreign( 'post_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'posts' );
    });
```

**Model User**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password'
];

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Post' );
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Comment' );
}
```

**Model Post**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'body'
];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'App\User' );
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Comment' );
}
```

**Model Comment**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'body'
];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'App\User' );
}

public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Post' );
}
```

**CommentController**

```
public function store( CommentRequest $request ) {
    Auth::user()->comments()->create( $request->all() );
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**PostController $request->all()**

```
"_token" => "TzdItNKU3TChVg50vAqdy1CYCrIR562l4Wv2z6ef"
"title" => "New Post"
"body" => "New text"
```

**CommentController $request->all()**

```
"_token" => "TzdItNKU3TChVg50vAqdy1CYCrIR562l4Wv2z6ef"
"body" => "New Comment"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Comment** model has a relation to **Post** models via **post_id** field and that field is **NOT NULL** in the database. Therefore all records in that table need to have that field filled. Moreover, due to the fact that you have a foreign key constraint on that field, it always needs to point to an existing row in Post table.

In your case it seems that whatever data is passed to your **Auth::user()->comments()->create()**, it either doesn't contain **post_id** field or **post_id** field is not marked as **fillable** in your **Comment** model.

I suggest you first check what **$request->all()** returns in your controller method. If the field is there, add **post_id** to the list of **fillable** fields in your **Comment** model:

```
protected $fillable = [ /** list all fields that should be fillable by create/update methods **/ ];
```

Comment: **PostController $request->all()** returns not **user_id** and it is not in the **fillable** array. But it works. However, **post_id** is not there. I've edited my post. I added the **fillable** arrays and the **$request->all()** from **PostController** and **CommentController**.

Comment: It works because you're calling "->comments()" on a user so Eloquent knows what user_id to set for those comments. But post needs to be linked to comments manually.

Comment: How can I do it cleverly? Something like this: 
public function store( CommentRequest $request, **$postId** ) {
  Auth::user()->comments()->create( $request->all()  );
  return redirect()->back();
 }
 and append **postId** to the request? Or is there a better way?

Comment: It depends where you store the post_id. Does it come from the URL? Or in the request body?

Comment: How did you define the route for this controller action?

Comment: **<form action="../comments/{{$objPost->id}}" class="form-comment" method="post">** and **Route::post( 'comments/{id}', 'CommentController@store' );** and **public function store( CommentRequest $request, $postId )**. It works! Thank you very much. If there is a better way, let me know, pls.

Comment: That's more or less how I'd do it: ->create(array_merge(['post_id' => $postId], $request->all()));

Comment: Just don't forget about validating user data :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this trick on internet which works very well in this case.

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

Schema::table('foo_products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->unsignedInteger('foo_type_id');
    $table->foreign('foo_type_id')->references('id')->on('foo_types');
});
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

You just have to disable the foreign key check before schema and then enable it after.